# Disable line width limit in run console

Tags: clion

The Run terminal in CLion wraps the output of my program automatically after a certain amount of characters. I run CLion on Windows 10.

[image: The Run terminal in CLion.]

How to disable these automatic line breaks?

Comment: Could you check the 
[solution for Windows OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52268686/how-can-i-expand-the-max-width-of-the-run-tool-window-in-clion-intellij)