# How can I expand the max width of the Run Tool Window in Clion/Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, clion

[image]

As you can see, there's plenty of space for the text to expand to the right, but it gets wrapped at 120 characters. I have tried turning off soft wrapping (the little button on the right side), I tried going into the settings, under editor -> general -> console, unchecking "use soft wraps in console", and increasing the "console commands history size", but none of these have worked. I'd like for the cout of my program to continue to the right, and ideally just make a horizontal scroll bar rather than wrapping or truncating. Is there a way to do this in CLion/Intellij?

Comment: Do you get this in IntelliJ iDEA also? Sound like CLion-specific: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-10624.

Comment: I never saw this in intellij...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

120 is the default value for windows console. To change the value 
 1. you can set the OS-wide system variable **CONSOLE_WIDTH**.
 2. setup **CONSOLE_WIDTH** inside you run configuration:

[image: Configuration editor]

then `Registry...` (aka `Help -> Find action -> Registry...)` got to be invoked to opt out value of `run.processes.with.pty`

[image: Registry...]

Comment: How exactly do I do this? What do you mean by OS-wide variable console_width?

Comment: In CLion: `Edit Configurations...|Run/Debug Configuration`, choose the Application you like to adjust, add the line **CONSOLE_WIDTH=200**.
In Window OS: please call **set CONSOLE_WIDTH=200** somewhere in start scripts, system or user profile. Please, read OS documentation for details.

Comment: This seems to not work lately. Using MSVC for toolchain here. Any hints how to get it "working" ?

Comment: Did you turn off in `Registry...` `run.processes.with.pty` [ ]?

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. Worked great in Clion 2020.1 on Windows 10 using CMake and MinGW

Comment: In PHPStorm 2019.3.4 I also disabled `run.anything.use.pty` option and now console width is ok.

Answer (score -3):

Using PyCharm, I had this issue when running commands automatically generated from my `Makefile`, and the `CONSOLE_WIDTH=200` solution didn't work.

In the end, what did work was to tick the `Use Cygwin` option in `Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Make`:

[image: "Use Cygwin" tickbox in Settings]