# Clion run window character limit per line

Tags: clion

Yo

Does any1 know how to remove that damn limit ?!

I have this in my debug pints:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhSVe.jpg

I tried going to Editor>General>Console and changing stuff there but no luck sadly.

TIA

Comment: Could you check the 
[solution for Windows OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52268686/how-can-i-expand-the-max-width-of-the-run-tool-window-in-clion-intellij)

Comment: @uta Tried, it did not help :- (

Comment: Did you turn off in `Registry...` 
`run.processes.with.pty` [ ]?

Comment: Nope, no idea. what registry? in regedit? Or in clion registry ? How do I do it? thanks!

Comment: @uta wow that helped!. But qDebug() does not print at all now. std::cout<< prints long lines(yay!) but no qDebug? :- (

Comment: It seems that in latest EAP this is now somehow fixed with the pty set to off! yay!