# How to stop CLion from automatic line breaking in string when printing to the Console in Python

Tags: python, windows, printing, clion, carriage-return

Surprisingly I didn't find an answer to this seemingly very common problem. In `Python` when I print something to the [`CLion Console`](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion) when the printed text is longer than 80 characters, an automatic `line break` is inserted. In hexadecimal I can see the inserted symbol is `carriage return` (`0D 0A`) on `Windows`. How can I stop this from happending?

Example:

```
print("99b17c2b92123eb0ba2a0afb2568d18247fc2b24385a65b8e2da7245bef278f799b17c2b92123eb0ba2a0afb2568d18247fc2b24385a65b8e2da7245bef278f7")
```

On the console it will automatically insert a line break after 80 characters:

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 203.7148.70)
99b17c2b92123eb0ba2a0afb2568d18247fc2b24385a65b8e2da7245bef278f799b17c2b92123eb0
ba2a0afb2568d18247fc2b24385a65b8e2da7245bef278f7
```

I just want this to be printed unmodified like as follows:

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 203.7148.70)
99b17c2b92123eb0ba2a0afb2568d18247fc2b24385a65b8e2da7245bef278f799b17c2b92123eb0ba2a0afb2568d18247fc2b24385a65b8e2da7245bef278f7
```

Comment: if you make the console wider, is the linebreak still there?

Comment: @Balduin: Yes, things not printed by `Python` don't have the line breaks. Maybe it's also important to note that I'm using the `CLion` console (an `IDE` for `C/C++/Python` development).

Comment: I'd check the IDE settings first. You could also check if the same script gives you linebreaks if run directly from a regular terminal instead of the IDE. Or you could pip the output to a txt file and see if the linebreaks show up there too.

Comment: it seems, people have the same issue: see [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360009295839-CLion-unnecessary-forced-line-wrap-in-console-output)

Comment: @Balduin: Thanks for the link. It works correctly in the regular terminal. The poster says he's on Linux but I'm on Windows. Same problem. However, I found a solution in their bug tracker.

Comment: Here is the [alternative method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52268686/how-can-i-expand-the-max-width-of-the-run-tool-window-in-clion-intellij/52290166#52290166) that is switching off `pty`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, this is a `CLion` bug which is still unresolved. However, a solution has been posted [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-17163):

> - go to `Help` | `Edit Custom VM Options`
> - when asked to create `.vmoption` file press OK
> - add `-Dwin.pty.cols=120` (the number here is for console output width) restart `CLion` You might want to use this because
>   `run.processes.with.pty` can be useful for an output of `C/C++`
>   applications.